# docuSign - envelopeViews : createRecipient

Tags: docusignapi

**ERROR: Content Type specified is not supported.**

Hi there, I am new to DocuSign and I am trying to learn the implementation from last couple of days. What I did so far is, created a developer account and created a QuickStart project.

**Goal**
I want to integrate the DocuSign API's in my application, but I don't really want the user to leave my application. I just want to make use of DocuSign within my app. - Embedded Signing

**What I did?**

I successfully created an envelope with a sample document and after that I have to get that URL to view (for Recipient).
So I called the below API:

** EnvelopeViews: createRecipient**
** POST - {{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/views/recipient**

All the details, like accountId, envelopeId are correct, along with that the request body that I pass with this is:

**Request Body**

```
{
    "authenticationMethod": "none",
    "clientUserId": "bcc49234-f30b-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "recipientId": "007",
    "returnUrl":"http://localhost",
    "userName": "user name"  
}
```

Note: * clientUserId is my Integration Key (please let me know if this is what I need to pass here or something else).*

**Response**

```
   {
           "errorCode": "INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE",
           "message": "Content Type specified is not supported."
   }
```

Note: Apart from the solution, please provide any link(s) to resources where I can easily see the implementation(as in my use case).

Answer (score 0):

Umair,
First `clientUserId` is a bit of a confusing term, it's not the IK (Integration Key) but any string you want. It is unique to the signer and the envelope. You choose it.

You can find a detailed example of this with code in 8 languages on the DocuSign Developer Center [How To Request Signature Through your app](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/) page.

I'm not clear how you make the API calls, if you are using [postman](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-please-mr-postman), there are headers that needs to be set. One of them is called `Content-Type` and it has to be set to **text/plain**.

Comment: Well, I set the Content-Type to application/json and it worked fine. Thank you very much for your help though. And also when I created the recipient, I had not set its clientUserId, which was creating this problem. It's done now. Thank you once again, mate.

Comment: One more thing that I would like to ask you, on EnvelopeViews: createRecipient we get the URL, that we can show to recipient (so that the recipient can view and sign the doc) has a very less expiry time. Can we anyway increase it's expiry time?

Comment: No, you cannot increase, it expires very quickly on purpose. It's a security measure. You have to generate it just before you need it. You cannot email this URL